# Fastest way to get the length of the intersection of two text arrays in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.3, array

This is what I am currently using:

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_intersect(a1 anyarray, a2 anyarray)
RETURNS anyarray AS
$$ 
  SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT unnest($1)
    INTERSECT SELECT unnest($2)
    ORDER BY 1
  );
$$ LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE STRICT;


--get the length:
select array_length ( array_intersect(array[...], array[...]), 1);
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Doesn't look like it for general purpose arrays. For integer arrays the `intarray` extension provides the `&` operator, but there doesn't seem to be a generalized one for all arrays despite the existence of the `&&` boolean test for overlapping arrays. It'd be nice to add, but ... well, take a look at the C source code for the PostgreSQL general purpose array functions and operators to see why there aren't as many as you might expect. The array API is horrid.

Comment: Thanks Craig. Ideally, I'm trying to get the Jaccard Similarity between two arrays, quickly. Any tips on getting Teodor's smlar extension to compile on Windows?

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue now.  I looked at converting my text elements to integers to use the integer indexing extensions.  Did you ever find a way to do this quickly?

Comment: What is the datatype you're using? How big are the arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You say you're looking for *"Jaccard Similarity between two arrays"*

   You may consider [MadLib which provides this](https://madlib.apache.org/docs/v1.10/linalg_8sql__in.html#ac1397ac9f4a35b3b67c3be05b5e1a828) as `dist_jaccard()`

   > Jaccard distance between two varchar vectors treated as sets.
2. You may want to try it without [`STRICT`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8455177/124486). That may be slowing it down.
3. You may want to use [`INTERSECT ALL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)) Especially if you know you don't have dupes in `$1`.
4. As Craig Ringer said in the comments you may want out [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) and consider using `&`.

To give a more accurate answer here,

- What are the datatypes?
- How many elements are we talking about on each array?
- How much exclusion does the `INTERSECT` provide?